# Adding a Menu Action to a view

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I want to add a menu action to my view, like this one from the Eclipse Console:

[image]

I managed to do something quite similar.. From the two actions that I want on the menu, one of them has a MenuCreator associated, but doing it this way sets this action to be the top one, or in other words, the one with the arrow to open the menu, and also, when I click it, instead of opening the menu it starts the code in the run method from the action.

[image]

I want the exact behavior from the console action, I want my 2 actions on the menu and a little icon on top to open this menu.. How can I do this?

The code so far:

```
private void createToolBar() {

    IToolBarManager toolBar = getViewSite().getActionBars().getToolBarManager();

    actionNovaDespesa = new OpenNewDespesa();
    actionNovaDespesa.setMenuCreator(new CustomActionMenu());
    toolBar.add(actionNovaDespesa);
}



public class CustomActionMenu implements IMenuCreator {

        private Menu menu;

        public Menu getMenu(Control parent) {

            menu = new Menu(parent);       

            MenuItem menuItemColaboradores = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH);
            menuItemColaboradores.setText(LabelVARS.DESPESA_COLABORADOR);
            menuItemColaboradores.setImage(Activator.getImageDescriptor(IconVARS.TOOLBAR_UTILIZADOR).createImage());
            menuItemColaboradores.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {

                    new OpenNewDespesaColaborador().run();
                }
            });  

            return menu;
        }

        public void dispose() {
            if(menu != null) {
                menu.dispose();
                menu = null;
            }
        }

        public Menu getMenu(Menu parent) {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your menu implement `IAction` as well as `IMenuCreator`. Something like:

```
  class DropDownAction extends Action implements IMenuCreator
  {
    private Menu menu;

    DropDownAction()
    {
      super("Name", IAction.AS_DROP_DOWN_MENU);

      setImageDescriptor(... image descriptor for button);

      setMenuCreator(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void dispose()
    {
      if (menu != null) {
        menu.dispose();
        menu = null;
      }
    }


    @Override
    public void runWithEvent(final Event event)
    {
      if (event.widget instanceof ToolItem)
        {
          final ToolItem toolItem = (ToolItem)event.widget;
          final Control control = toolItem.getParent();
          final Menu menu = getMenu(control);

          final Rectangle bounds = toolItem.getBounds();
          final Point topLeft = new Point(bounds.x, bounds.y + bounds.height);
          menu.setLocation(control.toDisplay(topLeft));
          menu.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Menu getMenu(final Control parent)
    {
      if (menu != null) {
        menu.dispose();
      }

      menu = new Menu(parent);

      // TODO add your menu items

      return menu;
    }   

    @Override
    public Menu getMenu(final Menu parent)
    {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! I wish Eclipse RCP would have more Documentation and places on the web to learn all this tricks..